# How to retain f:viewParam values after postback with validation failed

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, postback, viewparams

I have xhtml page with simple form. This page is using for several data tables. To specify data table (and so on), I use GET request parameters. xhtml page receive it through

```
  <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="page" name="page" value="#{itemsBean.page}"/>
  </f:metadata>
```

and pass again by the navigation rules like

```
  <navigation-case>
  <description>
  Global rule for going to the items page from any page  
  </description>
  <from-outcome>items</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/items.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <redirect>
    <view-param>
      <name>page</name>
      <value>#{itemsBean.page}</value>
    </view-param>  
  </redirect>  
  </navigation-case>
```

But if I use inputs in the xhtml file like this

```
  <h:inputText id="itemName" value="#{itemsBean.name}" 
    required="true" requiredMessage="Value for this field required!"/>
```

I cannot restore view param after trying to accepting form with no text in input. 
I tried to use hidden input for passing parameters

```
<h:inputHidden id="page" value="#{itemsBean.page}" />
```

, but seems like validation runs before and itemsBean.page is still empty. itemsBean is RequestScoped. What things I do wrong? How can I pass the param?

Thank you for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep passing request parameters to the subsequent request. In "plain vanilla" HTML you'd indeed have used `<input type="hidden">` for this, but the JSF `<h:inputHidden>` unfortunately doesn't work that way. In case of a general validation failure, caused by another input field, the model value associated with `<h:inputHidden>` won't be updated at all.

You should be using a `<f:param>` in the `UICommand` component instead to retain request parameters for the subsequent request. E.g.

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="page" value="#{param.page}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`<o:form>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form) of the [OmniFaces JSF utility library](http://omnifaces.org), it basically extends the `<h:form>` with an additional attribute `includeViewParams` which enables you to retain the view parameters for the subsequent request in the form action URL.

```
<o:form includeViewParams="true">
    ...
</o:form>
```

This may end up to be easier if you have multiple command buttons/links and ajax actions, and this would be the only way in case you'd like to retain the same URL during non-ajax postbacks.

Comment: Thanks! I just forget to try <f:param> tag in the commandButton. For the temprory solution, I remove the "required" and "requiredMessage" atributes from inputText and check values via itemsBean and navigation rules.