# Pass a parameter to dropzone save method using JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload, parameter-passing, dropzone.js

I have written the question about how to use dropzone.js with JSF ([Use dropzone with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018632/use-dropzone-with-jsf)) and it was correctly answered by BalusC.

However I want to pass a parameter to the save() method and I am not able to do it. I have the dropzone component in a page similar to this:
http://localhost:8080/application/image-album.xhtml?albumId=1

And in that page I have:

```
<h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" styleClass="dropzone">
            <div class="fallback">
                <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{uploadImageController.part}"/>
                <h:commandButton id="submit" value="submit" />
            </div>
        </h:form>
```

And in the UploadImageController I have:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  albumId = Long.valueOf(externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("albumId"));
}
```

So theoretically I could use the albumId in the save() method. However the init() method is being called three times, the first time with the value 1 and the other two with the value null so it fails by NullPointerException.

Any workaround to this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET request parameters can be set as bean property using `<f:viewParam>`.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="albumId" value="#{bean.albumId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

If you're using a `@ViewScoped` bean, then this will be remembered across all JSF POST form submits (postbacks) on the same view. If you're however using a `@RequestScoped` bean, then bean properties can be retained across postbacks using `<h:inputHidden>`.

```
<h:form ...>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.albumId}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

This only doesn't work properly when there's a conversion/validation failure on the form. If you're using conversion/validation on the very same form, then better use plain HTML `<input type="hidden">`.

```
<h:form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="albumId" value="#{bean.albumId}" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

The `<f:viewParam>` will take care that the bean property is properly set. There's no need to manually fiddle with `getRequestParameterMap()` the old fashioned JSF 1.x way.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for)
- [How to retain f:viewParam values after postback with validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314081/how-to-retain-fviewparam-values-after-postback-with-validation-failed/)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)